# How do I monitor gmail API usage from Microsoft Flow?

Tags: gmail-api, power-automate

I have used Microsoft Flow to check for new emails with specific labels using their gmail connector trigger 'when a new email arrives'.

Up until now I have had four flows running perfectly for over a year, until last Friday when errors started occurring.  I am now testing with just one flow, single concurrency, which runs every minute (Flow Plan 2).  The mailbox being checked receives at most 200 new messages per day, fairly spread out.

This is the error message which happens after the flow runs sucessfully 2-3 times a minute apart:

```
{
  "statusCode": 403,
  "message": "Out of call volume quota. Quota will be replenished in 23:01:41."
}
```

Microsoft claim this is related to the gmail API limit of no more than 60 calls per 60 seconds, even though the message above suggests a refresh of the quote in something close to 24 hours.  It seems more like we are hitting some kind of daily limit, but the only one I could find on the [gmail usage limits page](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota#concurrent_requests) is for 1,000,000 quota units per day, and I'm certain we are far short of that.

I have tried accessing quota usage from https://console.developers.google.com but since I didn't make a project and everything is setup from the Microsoft flow, there is no quota data shown.

Q: How can I verify the number of api calls being made from Microsoft Flow via the gmail connector, if that's even possible?

Note, I also started a [thread](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/Out-of-call-volume-quota-Trigger-When-a-new-email-arrives-gmail/m-p/344989#M8477) on the Microsoft Power users forum to get help, but I figure if it's gmail API related then I may get better answers here.

Edit 27th Aug: Resolution was to export the flows to a new microsoft account.  For whatever reason, the flows run fine on the new account (even though it has the same flow subscription).  Microsoft still cannot explain why the flows would halt on one account and not on another.

Comment: It seems Flow is throttling the Gmail API with the requests, like it's constantly looking for the new emails at every possible moment, which will quickly make you go over the quotas. I suggest you take a look at the MS Flow settings to make sure you make it wait a bit between checks just to avoid the quotas. Additionally, I would suggest you to open a [G Suite support case](https://support.google.com/a/answer/1047213?hl=en)  if you have an account, they will be able to take a better look at what's going on.

Comment: Thanks, it's an idea, but the flow checks for new emails every minute.  I can't see how that is going to make it go over the Gmail API quota.  The only way to know for sure though, is to be able to see how many API calls are being made, and that's the information I don't know how to obtain yet.  I will also open a G Suite support case.

Comment: Update:  I talked to Gsuite support and they say the gmail quota usage data is not available with any of the tools they have access to, since the usage is from Microsoft flow and not from any project I created myself.  So it's back to Microsoft.

Comment: In that case can you get support from Microsoft? they're making the calls, so like support said, definitely check with them.

Comment: Final update:  Microsoft confirmed a problem with a node that was handling the gmail connector.  After they restarted the node, the problems I was having with the flow on my original Microsoft account went away.

Comment: Glad to hear it's solved now!